# Enable setVolumeControlStream() when application is in background

Tags: android

I want to change the volume of the stream - `AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL` when the application is in the background (Paused or Stopped).

I tried using `setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL)`. It works perfectly when the app is in the foreground. But it switches back to changing the volume of the `DEFAULT_STREAM_TYPE` when in background.

Most media players(using `STREAM_MUSIC`) as well as VOIP applications like WhatsApp seem to have solved this issue.

Going through their code they don't seem to have used anything different.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can use broadcast reciever to perform such events . Like whem you press volume up key then the broadcast event will generate the the event and with that event you can perform your operations. All you need to register a broadcast reciever for volume up event in the manifest file . Once you registered the event in the manifest file you can use the volume up for your tasks . Create a class and extends it with broadcast reciever . and override the onrecieve method . Write your operations inside the onrecieve method. Whenever volume up event will be generated the broadcast reciever will listen the event and execute your task. 
This way you can achieve your task.